# Converting .xls to .pdf using Java(or not)

Tags: java, pdf-generation, jasper-reports, type-conversion, ireport

Is there a way to convert a **xls** file into a **pdf**?

I want to make a dynamical report directly to **pdf** file, but didn't find a way to make dynamic columns on iReport, so I've made a method on Java that exports to **xls** dynamically.

So I was wondering if is there a way to convert this file to **pdf**, but it need to be on a method from my code. Or if you have a better idea, it can be used too.

Maybe there's a way to make this **pdf** file from my code as I did with **xls**. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: see solutions in this post -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735697/how-to-convert-ms-excel-file-to-pdf-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using iText http://itextpdf.com/ - I've used it to create PDFs with columnar structure.

Comment: I've used DynamicJasper to create like this, it was easier than learning how to use iText. I found some of DynamicJasper codes in my code to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) directly, there are a couple report engines that sit on top of it:

- [Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) (using 2.1.7, the last MPL/LGPL version)
- [Jasper Reports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/) (which uses a Very Old version, 1.3.1 IIRC)

Comment: Instead of converting it, I created it with DynamicJasper

Answer (score 0):

This is a commercial solution:

http://www.dancrintea.ro/xls-to-pdf/

If you want open source try jakarta POI.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Muhimbi PDF Converter Services](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/04/convert-office-files-to-pdf-format-from.html). It comes with a Java compatible Web Services based interface and sample code. It does other things as well.

I worked on this application, so the usual disclaimer applies.